# Good upper bound for a certain sum

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, elementary-proofs, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given $\gamma \in [0, 1)$, an integer $N \ge 2$, and a decreasing null sequence of positive numbers $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_t,\ldots$, I'm interested in estimating the sum $S_N := \sum_{t=1}^N\gamma^t e_{N-t}$.

## Question

What is a good upper bound for $S_N$ for large $N$ ?

## Observations

Empirically, I'm observing (by plotting graphs) that $S_N \sim \dfrac{e_N}{1-\gamma}$, but I'm not able to prove this in general. My experiments have been for $e_t=at^{-b}$ (with $a,b>0$), $e_t = \ln(t)/t$, $e_t=1/\ln(t)$, $e_t=1/\ln(t)^2$, etc.

[image]
The case $e_t = at^{-b}$ can be established analytically. Indeed, a [tedious computation](https://mathoverflow.net/a/329893/78539) reveals that $S_N \sim \frac{1}{1-\gamma}N^{-b} \sim \frac{1}{1-\gamma}e_N$.

---

## Notes

- In my (abuse of notations), it's fine for $\sim$ to hide global multiplicative constants (e.g $e_1$, etc.).

Comment: It's impossible in general to have an upper bound that just depends on $e_N$, because there are no upper bounds on $e_1$.

Comment: Well the coefficient of $e_1$ is $\gamma^N$, which is pretty tiny. No ?

Comment: $\gamma^{N-1}$ you mean.  Maybe this is tiny, but $e_N$ could be much tinier.

Comment: (Yes, I meant $\gamma^{N-1}$, but this doesn't change much in the arguments :)  )

Comment: I've added to support the empirical claims.

Comment: So if $e_N = o(\gamma^{N})$ your conjecture is false.

Comment: Hum, there is a chance a slightly "repaired" version of the conjecture is correct. In your counterexample, one has $S_N = (N-1)\gamma^N$, and I predict it would be of order $\gamma^N$. The prediction is not that "off" after all. No ?

Comment: In my (abuse of notations), it's fine for $\sim$ to hide global multiplicative constants (e.g $e_1$, etc.).

Comment: If $e_t$ tends to 0 superexponentially fast, then the sum is dominated by $e_1\gamma^{N-1}$, which is a lot larger than $\frac{e_N}{1-\gamma}$. If on the other hand $\frac{e_{n+1}}{e_n}\rightarrow 1$, your observation is true. If $\liminf\frac{e_{n+1}}{e_n}=0$, the statement is also false, as $S_{N+1}\geq\gamma S_N$. So you need some smoothness and subexponential decrease for asymptotics, and at most exponential decrease for asymptotics up to a constant.

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta: in the accepted answer below, just to show that $S_N \lesssim e_N/(1-\gamma)$, it was needed that  $e_{n+1}/e_n \rightarrow 1$, **AND** that there exists a log-convex function $f$ such that $e_n = f(n)$ for sufficiently large $n$. Are you saying log-convexity assumption is not necessary ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, worries. This is indeed the case. See my answer below.

Comment: @YCor Note [this meta thread](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4902/tag-upper-bounds-is-nowhere-to-be-found) regarding this question -- your edit has undone the actions described there.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty thanks for letting me know. I've posted an answer there. It it leads to consensus that it's useful to have all these three tags distinct, I'll not delete it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
$
Of course, without further assumptions on the $e_t$'s, no good bound can be given. However, looking at your examples, it appears that you are primarily interested in situations where the $e_t$'s satisfy the following conditions: For some real constant $c\ge1$ and some positive log-convex real sequence $(f_t)$ we have the following: (i) $f_t\le e_t\le c f_t$ for all natural $t$ and (ii) $f_{t+1}/f_t\to1$ as $t\to\infty$, so that $\rho_N:=(f_N/f_1)^{1/(N-1)}\to1$ as $N\to\infty$. In fact, in all your examples except for $e_t=(\ln t)/t$, 
we can use $c=1$ and $f_t=e_t$ for all $t$.

So, for all $N$ large enough for the inequality $\ga<\rho_N$ to hold, we have 
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{t=1}^N\ga^t e_{N-t}\le c\sum_{t=1}^N\ga^t f_{N-t}\le c\sum_{t=1}^N \ga^t f_N^{1-t/(N-1)}f_1^{t/(N-1)}
 =cf_N\sum_{t=1}^N(\ga/\rho_N)^t\le cf_N\sum_{t=0}^\infty(\ga/\rho_N)^t
 =\frac{cf_N}{1-\ga/\rho_N}\lesssim\frac{ce_N}{1-\ga}, 
\end{equation}
as you observed empirically.

---

One can do similarly assuming (instead of the above conditions involving the $f_t$'s) that the sequence $(e_t)_{t=t_0}^\infty$ is log convex for some natural $t_0$ and $e_{t+1}/e_t\to1$ as $t\to\infty$. In all your examples we can take $t_0=1$ -- except for $e_t=(\ln t)/t$, where we can take $t_0=5$.

Comment: Great, thanks. After the discussions in the comments, I knew there had to be a kind of "correction" which would safe 80% of the conjecture, but couldn't quite work it out. The log-convexity sandwhich nails it indeed. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, someone has voted for the question to be closed. Is the question that "bad" ?

Comment: For the members who voted to close, yes it is bad. You seem to have a good answer from an interested and helpful member, so I would not worry about it.  Gerhard "Closing Is A Subjective Thing" Paseman, 2019.06.05.

Comment: Well, there should be some objectivism regarding voting to close a question, as this is a very strong form of (dis)engagement. Otherwise MO wouldn't be any different from random YouTube comments. No?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like we don't really need the log-convexity assumption in the accepted answer.

Indeed, define $\rho_N := e_{N} / e_{N-1}$ (with $\rho_1 := 1$), and suppose

> **Assumption.** $\liminf_N\rho_N \ge \rho$ (i.e $\exists N_0 > 0 \mid \rho_N \ge \rho\;\forall N \ge N_0$) for some $\rho > \gamma$.

Note that with the above assumption, for sufficiently large $t \le N$, we have $\rho_t \ge \rho$, and so $e_t = e_{N-1}(e_t/e_{t+1})(e_{t+1}/e_{t+2})\ldots(e_{N-2}/e_{N-1}) = e_{N-1}(\rho_t\rho_{t+1}\ldots\rho_{N-1})^{-1} \le e_{N-1}\rho^{-(N-t)}$. Thus, for $N \ge 2$, one computes
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{split}
S_N &:= \sum_{t=1}^{N-1}\gamma^t e_{N-t}=\sum_{t=1}^{N-1}\gamma^{N-t}e_t
\lesssim e_{N-1}\sum_{t=1}^{N-1}\gamma^{N-t}\rho^{-(N-t)}
=e_{N-1}\sum_{t=1}^{N-1}(\gamma/\rho)^t\\
&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \sim e_{N-1}\sum_{t=1}^{N-1}(\gamma/\rho)^t \le e_{N-1}\sum_{t=1}^\infty(\gamma/\rho)^t = \frac{\gamma}{\rho}\frac{e_{N-1}}{(1-\gamma/\rho)}.
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus $S_N \lesssim \dfrac{\gamma}{\rho}\dfrac{e_{N-1}}{(1-\gamma/\rho)}$. In particular, if $\rho=1$ as in the accepted answer, then $S_N \lesssim \dfrac{\gamma e_{N-1}}{1-\gamma}$.

Comment: You don’t need the ratios to be nonincreasing or even convergent for this. You only need that they are bounded away from $\gamma$, that is, there exists $\rho>\gamma$ such that $e_{n+1}/e_n\ge\rho$ for all $n$.

Comment: Yes, I just added that remark before seeing your comment entered at the same time  :)

Comment: Also, finitely many exceptions don't matter, hence just $\liminf e_{n+1}/e_n>\gamma$ is enough.

Comment: Good point. Thanks!